# What is stepper? Is it wizard?

Tags: ios, terminology, material-design

I have a doubt what is **stepper**? There is confusion in term i.e being used or explained in iOS and Google Material design.

Which is the right meaning of **stepper**? Is iOS or material design right or none?

Reference Link

iOS: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/steppers/

Material Design: https://material-ui.com/demos/steppers/

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the environment that you are developing in you could use either; however, searching stepper in regards to UX design returns more results leaning towards Google's definitions.

[UX Planet](https://uxplanet.org/progress-trackers-in-ux-design-4319cef1c600) uses *stepper* in the context of a stepped process, for example account registration or order delivery.

> Guiding users through a complex process by making it easy and intuitive is key to helping increase conversion rates. Any frustration along the way may cause them to leave and pursue other options.
>
> An easy-to-use stepped process helps users avoid frustration and successfully complete a primary task. In this article we will overview various uses of progress trackers and see how they can be implemented.

[image: UX Planet - Account creation example]

[image: UX Planet - Order delivery]

Wheras the iOS documentation seems to use a stepper in regards to a numerical selector, for example item quantity.

> A stepper is a two-segment control used to increase or decrease an incremental value. By default, one segment of a stepper displays a plus symbol and the other displays a minus symbol. These symbols can be replaced with custom images, if desired.

[image: iOS Design Guidelines - Stepper Control]

Neither are more "right" than the other, however using stepper to describe incrementing a value in a non-iOS oriented environment might cause confusion.

Comment: But the definition of a stepper in iOS is different.

Comment: Correct - my point was that technically neither are incorrect; however the usage of the term will vary depending on the development team in question - specifically whether or not they adhere to the iOS design standards.